# Removing &#039; from string

Tags: php

Currently I have the following strings.

```
$artist = 'Lookas';
$song = 'Can&#039;t Get Enough';
```

As you can see above, the `$song` portion contains random text appose to just placing a symbol which should look like this `'`, how can I solve this?

The title also returns this some times as well.. `&amp;` appose to returning the proper `&` symbol.

Comment: those aren't random text. those are [html entity codes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_entities.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Those are not "random" characters. It is a html number encoded apostrophe.

```
<?php
$song = 'Can&#039;t Get Enough';
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($song, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES'));
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(16) "Can't Get Enough"
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @Memor-X, those are HTML-entities.

If this is data that you're getting from your own database, then you're using `htmlspecialchars()` in the wrong place. If not, then I recommend [reading up](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) on what that function does, and you'll find out how to decode those entities.